# Puppet CRLs in an environment where 'puppet' doesn't resolve right

Tags: puppet, puppet-dashboard

Due to political reasons above the technical layer, the bareword `puppet` does not resolve to the correct puppetmaster for parts of our infrastructure. These areas have their own, independent puppetmaster and CA. Today I discovered that... we did something wrong somewhere.

Running this command on an agent-machine in one of these areas:

```
puppet certificate_revocation_list find crl --terminus rest
```

Give me an error similar to this one:

`Error: Could not call 'find' on 'certificate_revocation_list': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [unable to get certificate CRL for /CN=puppetmaster-wrong.example.com]`

When I try to run the puppet agent, I get a very similar one:

`Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [unable to get certificate CRL for /CN=puppetmaster-right.example.com]`

During the troubleshooting for this I found a command I wasn't aware of...

```
puppet config print ca_server
```

Which returns the bareword `puppet`. This is when the swearing happened, since `puppet` is a CNAME to puppetmaster-wrong.example.com. I have learned that I should have had `ca_server = puppetmaster-right.example.com` in our puppet.conf files all along, but never knew I had to have it in there.

This is the second such environment I'm setting up, and it is well broken.

The first one, set up the same, seems to work. And I don't know why. It's also some 300ms away from puppetmaster-wrong, so that may play part of it.

Is this a case of "burn it to the ground and do it right this time" (ca_server set from the beginning) or is this something I can dig myself out out of?

Answer (score 2):

If your agents are still able to check in to the master correctly, and there is no crossover between the two masters, then it should be just a matter of setting

```
[main]
ca_server = puppet-right.example.com
```

in /etc/puppet/puppet.conf with puppet.

I've tested this on one of my agents, it seems to work fine. I might be missing something, but I don't think this is a big deal to fix.